# Filtering responsed data from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to ask you, if there is a way to filter SearchRequestBuilder srb in ElasticSearch.
I have an index consists of companies. Every company has a document for English language and may has documents for other languages. So I want to bring all companies which has document for the selected from user language and if this company hasn't document for this language bring me English.

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are documents saved as a list in a company? Or are they separate documents conncted with company by some ID?

Answer (score 0):

Answer updated to return all companies using scrolling API.

```
QueryBuilder qb = termQuery("Document", "English");

SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch(test)
    .addSort(FieldSortBuilder.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.ASC)
    .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
    .setQuery(qb)
    .setSize(100).execute().actionGet(); //max of 100 hits will be returned for each scroll
//Scroll until no hits are returned
do {
     for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits().getHits()) {
    //Handle the hit...
     }

    scrollResp =client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId()).setScroll(new 
    TimeValue(60000)).execute().actionGet();
   } 
   while(scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length != 0); 
// Zero hit mark the end of the scroll and the while loop.
```

And you can just use a if block for returning companies with english document if no document is found for other languages.

Something like this

```
if(SearchResponse1 == null) //searchResponse for Non english language
{
(Search for documents in English)
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If i set setSize(1), I will bring 1 company but I want to bring all companies. And the second is, how I merge in one the SearchResponse?

Comment: You can use scrolling API to get all the companies.See updated answer.Not sure what do you mean by 'merge in one of the SerachResponse'